# SQL server multiple command exception catch in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, try-catch

i am executing multiple updates in a single command
for example:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
command.CommandText="executing first updateSP" +"executing second 
updateSP"+.....+"executing 10th updateSP"
try
{
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(sqlException ex)
{
ex.message;
}
```

if 2nd,3rd,4th, update is getting exception, but in catch block i am getting only one spupdate exception.
is there any way to get all the updates exception?

Comment: yes, do them in series. =)

Answer (score 0):

you could always use an array of SQL text commands, also I always use the connection to create the command:

```
string[] cmds = new string[3] {  sp1_SQL, sp2_SQL, sp3_SQL };
try
{
  foreach( string sql in cmds)
  {
     using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
     {
       command.CommandText = sql;
       var rtn = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
   }
}
catch(sqlException ex)
{
  ex.message;
}
```

This code will abort after the first exception, but if you want to continue to execute each statement regardless of exception (makes my tummy hurt) then move the try/catch into the `foreach`